# Create a program that calculates the square root of a number without using Math.sqrt

Tags: java

This is the formula that can be used to calculate the square root of a number.

```
result=(guess+(number/guess))/2;
```

For example, I need to get the square root of 9. First, I need to make a guess. For this one, it's 6. Although, I know that the square root of 9 is 3, I chose 6 to show how the program should work.

that makes...

```
result=(6+(9/6))/2 which is equal to 3.75.
```

To get the actual square root of 9, I need to make the result the new guess.The program should continue as...

```
result=(3.75+(9/3.75))/2 which is equal to 3.075.
```

This process should continue till difference between result and the result after it is equal to 0. For example

```
result=(3+(9/3))/2 is always equal to 3.
```

When the value of result is passed to guess, the next result will also be 3. That means 3 is the square root of nine.

Here's my code:

```
package javaPackage;

public class SquareRoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calcRoot();
    }

    public static void calcRoot(){
        double num=9;
        double guess=6;
        double result=0;

        while(Math.abs(guess-ans)!=0){
            result=(guess+(num/guess))/2;       
            guess=result;
        }
    System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Output

```
3.75
```

My problem is I can't compare the value of result and the previous result. Since guess is equal to result, the program immediately since guess and result are already equal. How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the variable `ans`?

Comment: Would it be cheating to use `Math.pow(num, 0.5)`?

Answer (score 3):

Just exchange the two statements in the while loop (and the initializations to avoid a division by zero):

```
public static void calcRoot(){
    double num=9;
    double guess=0;
    double result=6;

    while(Math.abs(guess-result)!=0){
        guess=result;
        result=(guess+(num/guess))/2;       
    }
System.out.print(result);
}
```

The trick is to have the old value still in `guess` and the new one in `result` when the test is executed.

And you should not test for `!= 0`, due to rounding errors this may not be achieved. Better test for some small value `>= 1e-7`

Comment: I changed it to >0.000000 and exchanged the two statements in the while loop but the result is now infinity.

Comment: I also changed the initial values.

Comment: It works now. I'll just have to understand how you did it. Thanks!

Comment: Added a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the result with the previous result you need to keep both of them in a variable.

This does a binary chop.

```
public static double sqrt(double ans) {
    if (ans < 1)
        return 1.0 / sqrt(1.0 / ans);
    double guess = 1;
    double add = ans / 2;
    while (add >= Math.ulp(guess)) {
        double guess2 = guess + add;
        double result = guess2 * guess2;
        if (result < ans)
            guess = guess2;
        else if (result == ans)
            return guess2;
        add /= 2;
    }
    return guess;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        System.out.println(sqrt(i) + " vs " + Math.sqrt(i));
}
```

prints

```
0.0 vs 0.0
1.0 vs 1.0
1.414213562373095 vs 1.4142135623730951
1.7320508075688772 vs 1.7320508075688772
2.0 vs 2.0
2.236067977499789 vs 2.23606797749979
2.449489742783178 vs 2.449489742783178
2.64575131106459 vs 2.6457513110645907
2.82842712474619 vs 2.8284271247461903
3.0 vs 3.0
3.162277660168379 vs 3.1622776601683795
```

and

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        System.out.println(i / 10.0 + ": " + sqrt(i / 10.0) + " vs " + Math.sqrt(i / 10.0));
```

prints

```
0.0: 0.0 vs 0.0
0.1: 0.31622776601683794 vs 0.31622776601683794
0.2: 0.4472135954999581 vs 0.4472135954999579
0.3: 0.5477225575051662 vs 0.5477225575051661
0.4: 0.6324555320336759 vs 0.6324555320336759
0.5: 0.7071067811865476 vs 0.7071067811865476
0.6: 0.7745966692414834 vs 0.7745966692414834
0.7: 0.8366600265340758 vs 0.8366600265340756
0.8: 0.894427190999916 vs 0.8944271909999159
0.9: 0.9486832980505138 vs 0.9486832980505138
1.0: 1.0 vs 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double sqrt(double number)
{
    double dd=number, sqi, sqrt=0;
    long i, b=0, e=0, c=1, z, d=(long)number, r=0, j;
    for (i=1l, sqi=1; ; i*=100l, sqi*=10)
    {
        if (i>dd)
        {
            i/=100;
            sqi/=10;
            j=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (z=0l; z<16; dd=(dd-(double)(r*i))*100, j/=100l, sqi/=10, z++)
    {
        r=(long)(dd/i);
        d=(e*100l)+r;
        int a=9;
        for (c=((b*10l)+a)*a; ; a--)
        {
            c=((b*10l)+a)*a;
            if (c<=d)
                break;
        }
        //if (a>=0)
        //    System.out.print(a);
        e=d-c;
        sqrt+=a*sqi;
        if (number==sqrt*sqrt && j==1)
            break;
        //if (j==1)
        //    System.out.print('.');
        b=b*10l+2l*(a);
    }
    return sqrt;
}
```

Sorry for the undefined variable names....but this program really works!
This program is based on long division method of finding square root

Answer (score 0):

Just create another variable to store the value of the previous guess.
This is the code:

```
package javaPackage;

public class SquareRoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calcRoot();
    }

    public static void calcRoot(){
        double num=9;
        double guess=6;
        double prevGuess=0;
        double result=0;

        while(Math.abs(guess-prevGuess)!=0){
            result=(guess+(num/guess))/2;
            prevGuess = guess;
            guess=result;
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance,following this code:

```
    public static double sqrt(double num) {
    double half = 0.5 * num;
    long bit = Double.doubleToLongBits(num);
    bit = 0x5fe6ec85e7de30daL - (bit >> 1);
    num = Double.longBitsToDouble(bit);

    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        num = num * (1.5f - half * num * num);
    }

    return 1 / num;
}
```

About the `magic` number `0x5fe6ec85e7de30daL`,you can see the [FAST INVERSE SQUARE ROOT](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf)
Let's see the performance,the test code:

```
    double test = 123456;

    //trigger the jit compiler
    for (int index = 0; index < 100000000; index++) {
        sqrt(test);
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < 100000000; index++) {
        Math.sqrt(test);
    }


    //performance
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (long index = 0; index < 10000000000L; index++) {
        sqrt(test);
    }
    System.out.println("this:"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (long index = 0; index < 10000000000L; index++) {
        Math.sqrt(test);
    }
    System.out.println("system:"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));


    System.out.println(sqrt(test));
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(test));
```

and the result is:

```
this:3327
system:3236
this result:351.363060095964
system result:351.363060095964
```